# Razor and half finishing html tags

Tags: c#, razor

How do I make this possible?

```
@if(item.i % 2 == 0)
{
   <div class="row">
}       

@if(item.i % 2 == 0)
{
   </div>
}
```

Without it complaining that I haven't finished a tag off and thus thinking I haven't put a `}` at the end of the if statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to prefix both lines with `@:` to prevent the Razor parser from parsing the HTML tags.

```
@if(item.i % 2 == 0)
{
   @:<div class="row">
}       

@if(item.i % 2 == 0)
{
   @:</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i'd do id this

```
@(item.i % 2 == 0 ? "<div class='row'>" : "</div>")
```

I think it'll work ;)

Hf !